# Trying to create a userform in VBA that returns a set of values specified based on criteria from data in an existing spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have this set of hypothetical data in a worksheet in Excel.

**Phone**    **Storage**    **Price**   **Color**

iPhone   32 GB      100     Black

Galaxy   64 GB      100     Black

Pixel    64 GB      200     Black

I would like to create a userform that will be displayed after clicking a button (I know how to do this). The userform will have list boxes, spin boxes, check boxes, frames, etc. for each of the 4 criteria. The user will then enter their desired criteria and the macro will output the available options or return an error if the specified criteria does not exist. Also, if a user does not want ot include a specific criteria (say color) then this should be considered.

Expected output:

If the user says Phone name and storage are irrelevant and checks 100 for price and black for color. The output should produce all the information for the iPhone and Galaxy.

Anything helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered converting your data into table and using the slicers instead of creating UserForm?
It's much easier and faster. It's also quite flexible, reliable and - if I have understood correctly your expectation - it should fit your needs.

To convert range into table you need to go to the "Insert" tab and click "Table" from "Tables Group" and input proper range.
Then select any cell in the created table, go to "Design" tab and click "Add slicer" (or sth like this - I have Polish Office, so don't know the exact English title of the button) from the "Tools" group. -> voila! You have four small  windows that allows filtering in any combination you need!

Comment: I appreciate the answer and will upvote, however I was explicitly looking for experience with userforms but thank you so much.

Comment: Ok, so if it's just for the training purposes, then I'd suggest to start with putting four ListBoxes on the form and setting MultiSelect property to 1 ("fmMultiSelectMulti") for each of them. It allows for selecting multiple elements from the list. I think you may also like "ListStyle" property setting to 1 ("fmListStyleOpen") to see a checkbox next to every available option. Then you'll need to populate the listboxes (each list may require removing duplicates and sorting) and add some events to them to apply filtering on the table.